# Create HTML table with 2 lines

Tags: html, css

This is the table thaT I have now and the table that I want to create:
[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
   <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
    </table><br><br>
    <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-1 th, td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Why are you  creating two separate tables?

Comment: What's up with the rowspan ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the correct use for a table. Why are you repeating the headers? It defeats the purpose of having headers. If you're looking to simply format some data into equal-sized boxes, check out [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: agree with the above.  if you want to repeat the headers, you are not creating a table.  You may want to consider looking into utilizing definition lists and incorporate some of the feedback from below and use css/flexbox to lay them out appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)

All you have to do is wrap your code with a parent div and have that flex. We can then also add some left text alignment to keep the data in columns and add some right margin to let it breath.

```css
.table-container {
  display: flex;
}

.table-1 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">   
    <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
    </table><br><br>
    <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using flex layout, but you shouldn't need that `<br><br>` in there, and they seem to make no difference. Just add some margin and/or padding if you _do_ need to create some space. (I know - they came from the OP original markup)

Comment: @StephenP I absolutely agree, I just left them there to show the OP that I just wrapped his code with a div (without needing to make any change).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<table class="table-1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>Bill Gates</td>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>Steve Jobs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
            <td>55577854</td>
            <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
            <td>55577854</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like the HTML only approach. The problem is that rowspan needs to be specified explicitly for this solution to work. Any change in the data and the design will break.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this?

```css
table th, td {
    text-align: left;
}
.name, .phone {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.space {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td class="name">Name:</td>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  <td class="space"></td>
  <td class="name">Name:</td>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="phone">Telephone:</td>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  <td class="space"></td>
  <td class="phone">Telephone:</td>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS '.table-1 {display:inline-block;}'
It's not the best choice, but you can fix it in few secs:

```
<style>
.table-1 th, td {
    text-align: left;

}
.table-1 {
    display:inline-block;
    }
</style>

<table class="table-1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>Bill Gates</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
            <td>55577854</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
 <table class="table-1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>Bill Gates</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
            <td>55577854</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an accepted answer, I wanted to show doing this without a `<table>` because I think these things are *not* tables, they are directory entries.

This shows an "entrylist" with a number of entries "entry" each containing a "name" and a "phone".  The labels are *not* repeated, they are added via CSS `:before` content generation.
Classes are used to describe what each thing ***is***, not how it looks.

The number of entries per row can be controlled by using flex layout styles.

```css
.entrylist {
  display: flex;
}
.entry {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding: 3px 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.entry .name, .entry .phone {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.entry *:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10ex;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.entry .name:before {
  content: 'Name:';
}
.entry .phone:before {
  content: 'Telephone:';
}
```

```html
<div class="entrylist">
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="name">Bill Gates</span>
    <span class="phone">55577854</span>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="name">Steve Jobs</span>
    <span class="phone">55533987</span>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="name">Elon Musk</span>
    <span class="phone">55599123</span>
  </div>
</div>
```